# xlSourceChart VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to export a pivot chart to html, however when I tried to do that the error appeared:

> This method is no longer supported in this version of excel

This is my code:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceChart, _
    "c:\test.html", "Sheet1", "Chart1", _
    xlHtmlChart, "", "")
    .Publish (True)
    .AutoRepublish = False
End With
```

PS: I don't want `xlHTMLStatic`, because I want to manipulate the chart in html.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Other than xlHTMLStatic is no longer supported.

Comment: This is dated in 2017:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/publishobjects-add-method-excel

Answer (score 0):

The only that you can do is to publish the whole sheet and keep `.Autorepublish=True`, with this way you can make changes to excel and when you save it, the changes will be  published to your Html file:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceSheet, "D:\desktop\test.htm", _
        "sheet1", "", xlHtmlStatic, "test_8891", "")
        .Publish (True)
        .AutoRepublish = True
    End With
End Sub
```